# Chrome extension not supporting code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have finally perfected my extension for Chrome, after asking 2 questions here. I am making it for personal use, based on an example one from a tutorial site, and what my version is meant to do is take a query input from a user, go to Flickr's API and return 24 images by searching that query. I opened the page as, well, a page, and it works perfectly. But when I try to open it as an extension, whatever the user types in, the query term doesn't change. I have therefore come to the conclusion that either some code isn't supported in chrome extensions or I'm doing something horribly wrong. If the former is correct, could you please specify what I can and can't use in extensions (or link me to somewhere that has the answer)? Note: yes, I do know that server-side languages don't work altogether. If, however, it is I that is doing something stupid, please tell me and, if possible, give me a hand in fixing this. Thanks in advance for any help offered. The code is below:

JS (popup.js):

```
var q = "cake"; //Default search term
var req;
function querySubmit() {
oForm = document.forms["queryForm"];
oText = oForm.elements["query"];
q = oText.value
document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = "";
req.open(
"GET",
"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?" +
    "method=flickr.photos.search&" +
    "api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&" +
    "text=" + q + "&" +
    "safe_search=1&" +  
    "content_type=1&" +  
    "sort=relevance&" +  
    "per_page=24",
true);
req.onload = showPhotos;
req.send(null);}

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
"GET",
"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?" +
    "method=flickr.photos.search&" +
    "api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&" +
    "text=" + q + "&" +
    "safe_search=1&" +  
    "content_type=1&" +  
    "sort=relevance&" +  
    "per_page=24",
true);
req.onload = showPhotos;
req.send(null);


function showPhotos() {
  var photos = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");

  for (var i = 0, photo; photo = photos[i]; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href",constructImageURL(photo));
    a.setAttribute("target","_blank");

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src",constructImageURL(photo));

    a.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("images").appendChild(a);
  }
}

function constructImageURL(photo) {
  return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
  ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
  "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
  "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
  "_s.jpg";
}
```

HTML (popup.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Teh popup</title>
<style>
body {
    min-width:357px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
img {
    margin:5px;
    border:2px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    }
</style>
<!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="images">
</div>
<form name="queryForm" onsubmit="querySubmit();return false" action="#">
Search: <input type='text' name='query'>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Flickr image searcher",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Searches images on Flickr wirtout opening another page.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "results.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onsubmit` handler in your HTML is inline JavaScript, which is not allowed in `manifest_version: 2`.

Instead, use `addEventListener` in your JS file to bind a `submit` event handler function to your form:

```
theForm.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    //...
    return false; // stop submission
});
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I'm about to try it out, but before I do, if the event the listener is, well, listening for is a submit event, shouldn't I attach it to the form rather than the button? So instead of `someButton.addEventListener` do `someForm.addEventListener`? It's the form that gets submitted after all, not the button... isn't it?

Comment: Also, a problem I had with getting it to at least work on a page is that when I submitted the form, the page refreshed, so all the variables got reset. I fixed that by putting `action=#"` and `return false` in my onsubmit event. Now that I've removed my onsubmit event altogether, should I add `return false` to the event listener?

Comment: Whoops, dump mistake on my part; you'd bind to the form, not the button.  `return false` does the same thing in a `submit` handler function as in `onsubmit` inline code (i.e., cancels sumission), so if you needed it before, keep it in the new function.

Comment: Alright, I tried it and it doesn't work; I suspect it is like so because I have done something wrong (again) :D I took everything that was in my querySubmit() function and pasted it into the event listener like so:
`document.forms["queryForm"].addEventListener("submit", function() {

//didn't place the full code here due to character limit

});`

And deleted the querySubmit() function and all its contents. So now what happens is that the initial request works, but when I put something into the form and click submit, nothing happens. I think I might've set up my listener badly. Help please D:

Comment: First test if the handler is firing at all, using a debug `console.log` or `alert`.  You can also check if it has been bound correctly, using Chrome's inspector (there's an "Event Listeners" section in accordian on the right).  If both of those are correct, then you need to look at your actual code in the function.

Comment: Actually, your problem is probably that you're trying attach the listener before the DOM is built.  You should attach the listener in reponse to the DOM being completed, like `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // add your event listeners here... }`.